# How do I setup Netrender on a cloud instance?

Tags: network

So,
I went ahead and built blender from git on my dreamhost cloud instance to try and see if I could use the cloud as a render service. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to set up this pipeline.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I built a headless make.

Has anyone done this before? Can you let me know how to set this up.

p.s. - If you have an opinion on why this is not a good idea, I'm not interested. I am taking this up as an idea that I want to test regardless of performance benefits at this stage.